# User not able connect to ejabberd

Tags: xml, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am using erlang 17.0, ejabberd 14.07 on mac os x. I have added some user in ejabberd localhost, now I want to connect using these clients, but when hit `http://localhost:5222` it gives following error.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='2345000850' from='savitriya.com' version='1.0'><stream:error><xml-not-well-formed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'></xml-not-well-formed></stream:error></stream:stream>
```

I have check log file as well but it shows that "Connection Accepted".

```
2014-09-02 10:56:39.436 [info] <0.425.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:313 (#Port<0.3632>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:50295 -> 127.0.0.1:5222
```

How to solve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://localhost:5222` is incorrect, as it means sending an HTTP request to port 5222 — and as an HTTP request is not XML, you naturally get an `xml-not-well-formed` error.  Connect to port 5222 using an XMPP client instead.